# Hard disk Won't Mount

Tags: linux-mint

I downloaded Mint 17.1 on a P4 1.6GHz PC with 1.25 Gb RAM. Installation was easy, on a  single hard drive (fully formatted NTFS), no self-set partitions. A message "device won't mount" or similar came up on the desktop and I can't use the hard drive. I'm new to all this. I don't undrstand programming.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to install linux on an ntfs partition. Are you trying to mount an external drive with ntfs .

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's an internal IDE 40Gb hard drive. There are posts scattered around that suggest  mounting can be done, but some suggest programming. I can't do this and am thinking of giving up Linux. I'm running XP>

Comment: Apparently I don't have a "privelege" to edit my last post. I should have said I let Mint manage and partition the hard drive as it wished without intervention from me. I believe tht Mint has its own type of partition.

Comment: Can you boot into linux.

Comment: Yes; the desktop comes up, but the hard drive icon doesn't appear. The CD and DVD drives do, but I haven't tried hem.

Comment: open a terminal by pressing 'ctrl+alt+t' and post the output of the following commands: `lsblk` and `blkid`

Comment: Have been invited to move to chat, but don't have enough points. Thank you for all your time to date. I'm running Linux on another PC, which is physically next to the one I'm now using but I installed an older version of Ubuntu on it in the hope of having access to the hard disk. I didn't get access. So I need to reinstall Mint. Is it OK if I come back to you later. Would you recommend me reformatting the hard drive?

Comment: name   maj:min    rm     size   ro    type    mountpoint   sda   8.0   0  38.2  0 disk      sda1    8:1     0   36.9g    0   part /    sda2   8:2      1k    0   part  sda5   8:5    0    1.2g      0   part [swap]  sr0    11:0   1   1024m   0  rom   sr1  11: 1   1  1024m   0   rom        blkid  just gave blkd    Sorry about the mess; can't reproduce table.

Comment: Please edit your question and post there the output from `sudo lsblk -f` in codeblock.

Comment: Execute `sudo blkid` and enter your password when asked. Edit the question to include output of both commands. Post the output according to code formatting rules of the site editor.

Comment: SAGA, Yes, Linux has its own partition type; I started out with a single internal freshly formatted hard drive with XP. I have found out how to mount the hard drive, CD ROM and DVD drives using Session and Startup>Application Autostart and using simple UDISKS commands to automount. Found a couple of posts to start, joined a few dots and this is a really easy way of getting devices to mount. Am happy to share; will need time to make a clear post.

Comment: BAHAMUT, SAGA, Your later post didn't appear on the page  until I'd added my above comment. Thank you for responding. The output from both your suggestions is to enter my password, but I'm not allowed to type anything in at all. But using UDISKS seems to have sorted the problem out.

Comment: I have to comment to see all posts (but I am new to forums).

Comment: Automounting devices with Mint 17.1 xfce. Menu>Settings>Disks. Select device to be automounted. Device number shown under RH box e.g. /dev/sda1. (A bug has been reported using “More actions” >edit mount options box. It does seem inconsistent). Menu>Settings>Session and startup>Appliction autostart. L.click Add. Name, type UDISKS; Description, type Autostart hard drive (or whatever); command mnt/dev/x where x is device number. Entry should appear in Session and startup – ensure checked. This can be done for DVD's, etc.

Comment: SECOND PART AUTOMOUNTING DEVICES IN MINT.  Menu>Settings>Removable Drives and Media;  Storage deals with memory stick mounting which seems to work, Multimedia with CD and DVD drives and portable music players. The CD rom and DVD icons don't showOpen disk;  then select  on the desktop as in “More Actions”, “Show in user Interface” had to be unchecked for them to mount. To play a disc Menu>VLC media player>media>Open disk;  then select disk.